# Extracting text from a txt file using batch

Tags: batch-file

So I have been missing with this extractor it works great, but need a bit of help

Original Script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL 

SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Folder\New folder 1\Folder A"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Folder\New folder 2\Folder A"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "name"^<"%sourcedir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt" ') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "location"^<"%sourcedir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt" ') do set /a end=%%a
(
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%sourcedir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt" ') do (
 IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
 )
)>"%destdir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt"
GOTO :EOF
```

Now like I mentions this works great when I set the script to match the file name 
in this example I have set this file name Homes in Texas.txt 
The problem I'm facing is I'm trying to make it read over 1000.txt files with all different names 
in many different folders

Here is the layout of my original files

```
New Folder 1
    >> New Folder A
         | (1) Homes in Texas.txt
         | (2) Homes in Ohio.txt
    >> New Folder B
         | (1) Homes in Austin.txt
         | (2) Homes in Houston.txt
    >> New Folder C
         | New Folder 1
               | (1) Homes in Katy.txt
               | (2) Homes in Dallas.txt
```

Inside if each folder I have between 20 and 100 txt files 
This script is only designed to edit 1 file at a time and I really need it to edit multiple files 
Now inside each text file I have over 500 lines (rows), and all I need is to extract between 2 sets of lines

It will extract `Name, Location` and everything between 
It will also extract `City, and Place` from the same file

I have 4 codes to search within 1 files, and I would like for the Destination to have everything it copied from 1 file to have the same original file name, and both sets of codes to be in one file

Now the end results should look like this

```
New Folder 2
    >> New Folder A
         | (1) Homes in Texas.txt
         | (2) Homes in Ohio.txt
    >> New Folder B
         | (1) Homes in Austin.txt
         | (2) Homes in Houston.txt
    >> New Folder C
         | New Folder 1
               | (1) Homes in Katy.txt
               | (2) Homes in Dallas.txt
```

It would look exactly the same as the original, BUT the context of the files will only have what was extracted nothing more

What I did to get both sets of codes extracted, was I double my script. Now I know it's bad practice, but I get the double extractions I need but in two separate files

This is my modified scripts that reads both and extracts what I need

```
    @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL 
    
    SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Folder\New folder 1\Folder A"
    SET "destdir=C:\Users\user\Desktop\My Folder\New folder 2\Folder A"
    
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "name"^<"%sourcedir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt" ') do set /a start=%%a
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "location"^<"%sourcedir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt" ') do set /a end=%%a
    (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%sourcedir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt" ') do (
     IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
     )
    )>"%destdir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt"

    for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "City"^<"%sourcedir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt" ') do set /a start=%%a
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "Place"^<"%sourcedir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt" ') do set /a end=%%a
    (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<"%sourcedir%\(1) Homes in Texas.txt" ') do (
     IF %%a geq %start% IF %%a leq %end% ECHO(%%b
     )
    )>"%destdir%\(2) Homes in Texas.txt"
    GOTO :EOF
```

This is my end results when I do it this way, when I place the bat file directly in the folder where the file is located

```
New Folder 2
    >> New Folder A 
         | (1) Homes in Texas.txt
         | (2) Homes in Texas.txt
```

I have been doing a lot of research on setting this up, but I can't get it done

Comment: Consider piping the output of a `Dir` command that uses a search pattern containing wildcards for the filename to be searched into `findstr`

Answer (score 1):

You have got multiple pairs of begin and end tokens (`Name`/`Location`, `City`/`Place`) that define what part of the source files to copy to the destination files, which could define ranges that somewhat overlap, which would lead to duplicate lines. To avoid that, check whether the current line is within one of the ranges and set a flag variable in case, but do not clear it if not (except for an initial clearance), then write the current line only when that flag is set, so there is only a single write operation per line.

To build the same directory hierarchy in the destination, paths relative to the source root directory are needed, which I usually derive using the `xcopy` command, together with its options `/S` or `/E` (to recurse into sub-directories) and `/L` (to just list files but not to copy anything).

The above mentioned techniques are implemented in the following script – see all the explanatory remarks:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=%~dp0New Folder 1"
set "_TARGET=%~dp0New Folder 2"
set "_MASK=(*) Homes in *.txt"

rem // Define pairs of begin and end tokens:
set "$TOKEN_BEGIN[0]=Name"
set "$TOKEN_END[0]=Location"
set "$TOKEN_BEGIN[1]=City"
set "$TOKEN_END[1]=Place"

rem // Change into source directory:
pushd "%_SOURCE%" && (
    rem // Loop through all matching files and return their paths relative to the source directory:
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('xcopy /L /S ".\%_MASK%" "%TEMP%" ^| find ".\"') do (
        rem // Create respective sub-directory in the target directory:
        2> nul md "%_TARGET%\%%F\.."
        rem // Write to respective target file:
        > "%_TARGET%\%%F" (
            rem /* Read from current source file and prefix each line with line number plus colon;
            rem    the whole file becomes read here, so there is no interference with later reads: */
            for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%%F"') do (
                rem // Get current line number and line string with the prefix:
                2> nul set /A "NUM=%%L" & set "LINE=%%L" & set "FLAG="
                rem // Loop through pairs of begin and end tokens:
                for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%A in ('2^> nul set "$TOKEN_BEGIN["') do (
                    for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%D in ('2^> nul set "$TOKEN_END[%%A]"') do (
                        rem // Determine first line position of current begin token:
                        set "BEGIN="
                        for /F "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /N /R /C:"\<%%B\>" "%%F"') do (
                            if not defined BEGIN set "BEGIN=%%N"
                        )
                        rem // Determine last line position of current end token:
                        set /A "BEGIN+=!BEGIN*0x7FFFFFF, END=0"
                        for /F "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /N /R /C:"\<%%E\>" "%%F"') do (
                            set "END=%%N"
                        )
                        rem /* Set a flag when the line number of the current line lies in the range defined by
                        rem    the current pair of begin and end tokens, though never clear the flag here: */
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                        if !NUM! geq !BEGIN! (if !NUM! leq !END! (endlocal & set "FLAG=#") else endlocal) else endlocal
                    )
                )
                rem // Write currently iterated line when the flag is set:
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                if defined FLAG echo(!LINE:*:=!
                endlocal
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Return from source directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Oh man, I would of never figured that out, I see the changes you made, and I have tested it, and it works great, BUT, and I think it has to do with the xcopy, but it takes about 2 minutes per file, and I have over 4000 files easy, is there a way to fix that, also thanks for this `%~dp0`, I've been looking on how to setup a universal Source and Destination, for many of my files

Comment: I have this in a file, and there is more to it, but could something like this be use `FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "%sourcedir%\(*)*.txt"') DO (` this script reads everything in folder 1 and it's subs, and sends it to another folder 2 and it's subs, but this one edit my content inside the files, like it replace names with other names, so could something like this be used, I'm looking at now to see if I can find a way to use this, but I am not sure how to intergrade it

Comment: Well, I am using `xcopy /L /S` (`/L` tells the command to not copy anything but to list files it would copy without `/L`) for the same purpose as you use `dir /S /B /A:-D`, with the difference that `xcopy` returns *relative* paths and `dir /S` returns *absolute* ones, so I can recreate the same sub-directory hierarchy at the destination location…

Comment: Thanks for the help, your script works great. I have check the answer, but for the thousands of files I have, it would take to long, I have updated my original script, but would like to update it with a `(%source%\*.txt)`, and for it to copy file name to `%target%` could you help me with that, the script I'm asking the question on is lightning fast, if I can I will update my question to show my updated script

Comment: Could you help me with setting up `(1) *.txt` to my latest script, I can deal with no Sub Folder, but I would really like to use the wildcard, I do appreciate the help you provided, but the script edits a file every 2 minutes, and to edit over 5000 files well that's just a lot of minutes...lol, with my latest script it takes 1 sec per file and all I need help with really is using the wildcard to replace `FILE` and `FILENAME` parts in my script

Comment: Let me suggest that you roll back the latest edit of your question and ask a new one instead (you can of course insert a link to this one), because as it stands now the answer does not really cover the revised question any more…

Comment: I want to thank you for your help, I now have learned how to improve my Script, and now I can extract all my files in lighting speeds. Your script did help me a ton, while I was working on my original script, when I left the house I would leave your script running, for hours, it only did a few folders, but that is a few less to worry about - Once again Thank you